# Traefik : redirect non-www to www doesn't work

Tags: docker, https, traefik, http-redirect

Here's my use case :
I'm using traefik with Docker.
I have my website on https://www.example.com.
I want :

- All HTTP redirected to HTTPS
- All weird domains and subdomains (https://example.com, https://www.example.app, https://example.app) redirected to https://www.example.com

I have created two middlewares in my traefik.yml :
`        - traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.scheme=https
- traefik.http.middlewares.https-redirect.redirectscheme.permanent=true

```
    - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-www.redirectregex.regex=.+
    - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-www.redirectregex.replacement=https://www.example.com
    - traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-www.redirectregex.permanent=true`
```

in my front-end yml I have this :

`...

- traefik.http.routers.front-http.entrypoints=http
- traefik.http.routers.front-http.rule=Host(`example.com`)
- traefik.http.routers.front-http.middlewares=https-redirect
- traefik.http.routers.front-https-redirect.entrypoints=https
- traefik.http.routers.front-https-redirect.rule=Host(`example.com`, `www.example.app`, `example.app`)
- traefik.http.routers.front-https-redirect.middlewares=redirect-www
- traefik.http.routers.front-https.entrypoints=https
- traefik.http.routers.front-https.rule=Host(`www.example.com`)
- traefik.http.routers.front-https.tls=true
- traefik.http.routers.front-https.middlewares=security
- traefik.http.routers.front-https.tls.options=tls12@file
- traefik.http.routers.front-https.tls.certresolver=le
- traefik.http.services.front.loadbalancer.passHostHeader=true
- traefik.http.services.front.loadbalancer.server.port=80
  ...`

The redirect from HTTP to HTTP works.
But I get an SSL error and not a redirect on all weird domains and subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

As I see that you mention that you created middleware in traefik.yml , The middleware should be initiate in dynamic.yml file.

and in traefik.yml you should set SSL in there.